# Estimating number drawn from one distribution based on sum of that number and number drawn from another distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, convolution, uniform-distribution

I have been working on this for several days and have been unable to come up with an answer. The problem is very simple to state, but it seems difficult to solve.

A computer draws a number $x$ at random from a uniform distribution between $a$ and $b$. The computer also draws a number $y$ from a normal distribution with mean $m$ and standard deviation $s$. The computer then calculates $z = x + y$. The computer reports $z$ but it does not report $x$ or $y$. Calculate the expected value of $x$ given $z$.

So far, I have noted that the probability distribution function producing $z$ is the convolution of the uniform and normal probability distribution functions producing $x$ and $y$, respectively. And I believe that I need to use Bayes' Theorem to determine the value of $x$ given $z$, but I am stuck soon beyond that point. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are the other parameters ($a,b,m,s$) known or assumed to be unknown?

Comment: Hans, three parameters are known and fixed (a = 0, b = 1, m = 0) and I need to be able to solve for any given s >= 0. It is OK if the final answer has integrals or derivatives that cannot be simplified further.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say explicitly that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random
variables but since you use convolution to compute the density
of $Z = X+Y$, I expect that you have been told, or are
assuming,
that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Here is one way to approach the problem.

Since $a = 0, b = 1, m = 0$, the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$f_{X.Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-y^2/2s^2), ~0 \leq x \leq 1,
-\infty < y < \infty.$$
From this, figure out the joint density $f_{X,Z}(x,z)$ of $(X, X+Y) = (X,Z)$ using 
standard methods (Jacobians will be involved) and then 
$$f_{X|Z}(x|z) = \frac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{f_Z(z)} 
= \frac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Z}(x,z)\mathrm dx}.$$
From this, you can calculate 
$$E[X|Z] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{X|Z}(x|z) \mathrm dx.$$
Alternatively, since conditioned on $X = x$, $Z$ is a Gaussian
random variable with mean $x$ and variance $s^2$,
$$f_{X|Z}(x|z) = \frac{f_{Z|X}(z|x)f_X(x)}{f_Z(z)} 
= \frac{1}{f_Z(z)}\cdot\frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(x-z)^2/2s^2),
 ~ 0 \leq x \leq 1$$
where now $f_Z(z)$ can be recognized as the constant that makes
the function on the right a probability density and easily
expressible in terms of the standard Gaussian distribution
$\Phi(\cdot)$ or the $\text{erf}$ function. You will need
to use the fact that $x\exp(-x^2/2)$ is a perfect integral
in computing $E[X|Z]$

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful exposition. I am still having trouble completing the problem. Would you or anyone else be willing to complete either of the techniques (or both as a way of verifying the answer)?

Comment: Hint: $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(x-z)^2/2s^2) \mathrm dx = \Phi\left(\frac{1-z}{s}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{-z}{s}\right)$$ (figure out why this is so!) and so you have the value of $f_Z(z)$ (remember that it is just a constant; the RHS is a function of $x$). As I suggested, to find $E[X|Z=z]$, you need to write the integrand as $$x\exp(-(x-z)^2/2s^2) = s^2[(x-z)/s^2]\exp(-(x-z)^2/2s^2) +z\exp(-(x-z)^2/2s^2)$$ and then use the fact that one term is a perfect integral and the other gives a difference of $\Phi(\cdot)$'s upon integration.

Comment: I think that one thing I need to do is calculate $f_{z}(z) = f_{x+y}(z)$, and based on the definition of convolution, that produces $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{x}(t)f_{y}(z-t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1*\frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(z-t)^2}{2s^2})dt$$. Does this seem to be on the right track?

Comment: Meanwhile, $$E(f_{x|z}) = \int_0^1 xf_{x|z}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{f_{z}(z)}\frac{1}{s\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2 s^2}}dx$$ so I need to multiply $\frac{1}{f_{z}(z)s\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ by $\int_0^1 x e^{-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2 s^2}} \, dx$. That integral evaluates to $$\frac{1}{2} s \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } z \text{erf}\left(\frac{1-z}{\sqrt{2} s}\right)+\sqrt{2 \pi } z \text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2} s}\right)+2 s \left(e^{-\frac{z^2}{2 s^2}}-e^{-\frac{(z-1)^2}{2 s^2}}\right)\right),$$ so if that's right, all I need is $f_{z}(z)$.

Comment: The convolution integral that you need to compute to get $f_Z(z)$ is the area between $0$ and $1$ under a normal density with mean $z$ and standard deviation $s$.  It can be expressed in terms of the erf function, but cannot be expressed in terms of "elementary" functions such as exp, sin, cos, log etc

Comment: @mbabramo:  If you think this is helpful, as you say in your first comment, you could accept or at least upvote it.  To accept, click the check mark next to the answer.  To upvote, the double up arrow.